# get data stream java - working with java stream api

Tags: java, data-stream

i got an assignment working with data stream and java.
what i need to do is write a java class connecting to Data Streams given and API for it.

```
URI:http://<hostname>/ws/DataStream

HTTP operations supported:
GET: query one or more data streams

Elements include:

cstId - customer ID of customer that owns the data stream
streamId - the stream ID
forwardTo - comma separated list of streams to replicate data points to
```

GET

GET is used to retrieve a list of data streams, or a specific stream by its ID

```
Example #1:
To get a list of all data streams:
GET ws/DataStream
Returns a list of data streams.
Example #2:
To get information about a specific data stream using its stream ID:
GET ws/DataStream/{streamId}
```

i understand how its works ,

1. How do i create a class to the get this values?
2. What kind of objects do i need to use to store them
3. How Can i insert them for example to a Data Base ?